# Java - Configure Application to (Max screen size - dock height)

Tags: java, macos, swing, jframe

On MAC computers theres the dock on the side or bottom of the screen, I need to be able to configure the application to start at the maximum size minus the height of the dock, so the application fills all available space.

At the moment i've got a solution where I set it to the maximum screen size, the OS then auto-resizes it to the dock and then I lock the resize property. This is however very code-messy, bits of code are in various different threads and it takes a lot of compromise.

Is there any easy way to get the height + position of the dock so I can configure the main JFrame size easily?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getScreenInsets%28java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration%29 - may be what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to be able to configure the application to start at the maximum size minus the height of the dock, so the application fills all available space.

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```